# Can the chain rule be proven using linear approximation?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, chain-rule

I have heard it been said that the single-variable chain rule can be proven using the notion that the derivative gives the "best" linear approximation of a function around a point, in the sense that if $f$ is differentiable at $x$, then $f'(x)$ is the unique number such that
$$
\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{\bigl(f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)\bigr)-f'(x)\Delta x}{\Delta x}=0 \, .
$$
This means that we can write
$$
f(x+\Delta x) = f(x) + f'(x)\Delta x + r(\Delta x) \, ,
$$
where the remainder term $r(\Delta x)$ is "small" in the sense that $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{r(\Delta x)}{\Delta x}=0$. I have never read a calculus book that uses this idea to prove the chain rule, and so I tried to come up with my own proof. Is it correct?

---

> **THEOREM: The chain rule**. Suppose that $g$ is differentiable at $x$, and $f$ is differentiable at $g(x)$. Then, $f \circ g$ is differentiable at $x$, and
> $$
> (f \circ g)'(x)=f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x) \, .
> $$

The basic idea behind my purported proof is that
$$
f(g(x+\Delta x))\approx f(g(x)+g'(x)\Delta x) \approx f(g(x))+f'(g(x))g'(x)\Delta x \, .
$$
First, we will make the following definition out of convenience:

> **DEFINITION**: We say that a remainder $r(t)$ is *small* as $t\to0$ if $\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{r(t)}{t}=0$.

Since $g$ is differentiable at $x$,
$$
\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{\bigl(g(x+\Delta x)-g(x)\bigr)-g'(x)\Delta x}{\Delta x} = 0 \, .
$$
If we define $r_1(\Delta x)=\bigl(g(x+\Delta x)-g(x)\bigr)-g'(x)\Delta x$, then $r_1(\Delta x)$ is small as $\Delta x \to 0$.
In a similar fashion, $f$ is differentiable at $g(x)$, and so
$$
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\bigl(f(g(x)+h)-f(g(x))\bigr)-f'(g(x))h}{h}=0 \, .
$$
If we define $r_2(h)=\bigl(f(g(x)+h)-f(g(x))\bigr)-f'(g(x))h$, then $r_2(h)$ is small as $h\to0$. By keeping track of the remainders $r_1$ and $r_2$, we can show that $\bigl((f \circ g)(x+\Delta x)-(f \circ g)(x)\bigr)-f'(g(x))g'(x)\Delta x$ is small as $\Delta x \to 0$, and thus $(f \circ g)'(x) = f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$. For ease of notation, let $\Delta u = g'(x)\Delta x+r_1(\Delta x)$. Then,
\begin{align}
f(g(x+\Delta x)) &= f(g(x)+\Delta u) \\[4pt]
&= f(g(x)) + f'(g(x))\Delta u + r_2(\Delta u) \\[4pt]
&= f(g(x)) + f'(g(x))g'(x)\Delta x + f'(g(x))r_1(\Delta x)+r_2(\Delta u) \, .
\end{align}
We are left with two remainder terms: $f'(g(x))r_1(\Delta x)$ and $r_2(\Delta u)$. The first is obviously small as $\Delta x \to 0$. To show that $r_2(\Delta u)$ is small as $\Delta x \to 0$, define the functions $\psi$ and $\phi$:
\begin{align}
\psi(\Delta x) &= \Delta u = g'(x)\Delta x+r_1(\Delta x) \, ,\\[5pt]
\phi(h)&=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{r_2(h)}{h} &\text{if $h\neq0$} \\
0 &\text{if $h=0$.}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
It is easy to show that $\psi$ is continuous at $0$, and that $\phi$ is continuous at $\psi(0)=0$. Hence, $\phi \circ \psi$ is continuous at $0$, meaning that
$$
\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\phi(\psi(\Delta x))=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{r_2(\psi(\Delta x))}{\psi(\Delta x)}=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{r_2(\Delta u)}{\Delta u} = 0 \, .
$$
This completes the proof.

Comment: Take a look at [Loomis and Sternberg's Advanced Calculus](http://people.math.harvard.edu/~shlomo/docs/Advanced_Calculus.pdf) section 3.5 for a treatment of the big and little o (Theorem 5.1 tells you the various rules for manipulating these symbols), and section 3.6 for applying these to prove the chain rule (Theorem 6.2). Sure, this is in the setting of multivariable calculus, but literally no part of the proof is simplified by assuming finite or single-dimension.

Comment: @peek-a-boo: Thanks peek-a-boo. That book is very nicely put together. Is this something that you would recommend that I read after finishing *Calculus* by Spivak? are there any other recommendations you have?

Comment: Sure, after Spivak's *Calculus*, you'll be well equipped to read Loomis and Sternberg. After *Calculus*, people usually go on to read Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds or Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds. As a personal preference, I rate it as Munkres<Spivak<<<Loomis (I've read Spivak completely, Munkres only when I got stuck with Spivak, and I read about a decent amount of Loomis). Loomis is definitely not easy; the material is abstract, but well explained. Spivak's CoM is very tersely written (unlike *Calculus*), so even though Loomis is more abstract/general, I think it is much better

Comment: Though I have to say, I read Loomis and Spivak side-by-side, paying just as much attention to each book. Note that Duistermaat and Kolk have a two-volume series on (multivariable) differential and integral calculus. This is also very detailed, and they have a VERY huge set of problems, which you will definitely find beneficial, but I personally found Loomis and Spivak as better books to read/learn from. I'm sure other books exist, but these are the ones I have a decent amount of experience with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof works, but it could be made much cleaner (and closer to your "basic idea") with the help of [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). In particular, we will say that $r(\Delta x) = o(\Delta x)$ if
$$
\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{r(\Delta x)}{\Delta x} = 0.
$$
Moreover, to make everything easier to type, I will write $h$ instead of $\Delta x$.

---

Note that $f'(x)$ is the unique function for which $f(x + h) = f(x) + f'(x) h + o(h)$ (and may be defined as such). With that, we note that
\begin{align}
f(g(x + h)) &= f(g(x) + g'(x)h + o(h)) 
\\ &= f(g(x)) + f'(g(x))(g'(x)h + o(h))h + o(h)
\\ &= f(g(x)) + f'(g(x))g'(x) h + [f'(g(x))o(h) h  + o(h)]
\\ & = f(g(x)) + f'(g(x))g'(x) \cdot h + o(h).
\end{align}
Note that the statement
$$
f'(g(x))o(h) h  + o(h) = o(h)
$$
is shorthand for your statement regarding limits. By our "definition" of the derivative, we conclude that $f'(g(x))g'(x)$ is the derivative of $f \circ g$ at $x$, which is what we wanted.

Comment: That's [*little* o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)!

Comment: @Hans I've never heard it described as such; I'm used to "big o notation" being synonymous with Bachmann-Landau notation as a whole.

Comment: Well, it's described as such in the Wikipedia article that you yourself linked to (in the section that I linked to)... ;-)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, Ben. As a beginner to Landau notation, I don't know how to parse "$f'(g(x))o(h)h+o(h) = o(h)$". Using the definition that you have provided, this seems to be mean $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f'(g(x))o(h)h+o(h)}{h}=0 \, ,$$but I don't know what *that*  means? Does $o(h)$ refer to any function such that $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{o(h)}{h}=0$?

Comment: @BenGrossmann: If you could help clarify this, then I'd find that very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @Joe Sorry, it looks like your first comment didn't give me a notification. It's difficult to explain well, but I'll do my best. You essentially have the right idea: $o(h)$ really denotes the set of **all** functions $f$ with the property that $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h} = 0$, and in the expression $f(h) = g(h) + o(h)$, $o(h)$ is a placeholder for some (otherwise unspecified) element  of this set. The statement $C\cdot o(h)\cdot h + o(h)  = o(h)$ means that for any two functions $f,g \in o(h)$, the function $C \cdot f(h) \cdot h + g(h)$ is also an element of the set $o(h)$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann: Sorry for the late reply, but I think I understand now. The statement $f'(g(x))o(h)h+o(h)=o(h)$ is actually a shorthand for: if $\phi$ and $\psi$ are any two functions that satisfy $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\phi(h)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\psi(h)}{h}=0$, then
$$
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f'(g(x))\phi(h)h+\psi(h)}{h}=0 \, .
$$
Hence, $f(g(x+h))=f(g(x))+f'(g(x))g'(x)+o(h)$, and since $(f \circ g)'(x)$ is the unique number with the property that $f(g(x+h))=f(g(x))+(f \circ g)'(x)+o(h)$, we conclude that $(f \circ g)'(x)=f'(g(x))g'(x)$. Is that correct?

Comment: @Joe Yes, that's exactly it